# Why don't most programming languages accept commas in number?

Tags: syntax, numbers, programming-languages

Why can't we write

```
int n=1,000;
```

?

Why the programming languages aren't designed to allow commas? Will we run into any trouble if it allows commas?

Comment: In Swith you can use `_`, e.g. `let n = 1_000`

Comment: I think most languages I used support `_` in integer literals. I guess commas  are used to separate parameters in method/function calls. So using commas in numbers may cause confusion to the compiler and the one reading code?

Comment: because it is a reserved character for syntax

Answer (score 6):

Because `,` is often an operator or has a special meaning in most languages.

It would therefore be difficult or impossible to figure out whether `setColor(4,242,242)` was a call with three arguments (4, 242 and 242) or a single argument (4242242).

Some languages, like Swift, do accept numbers with `_` to ease reading. For example `1_000` is the same as `1000`.

For more reference on parsing I suggest you read [the Wikipedia article *Lexical analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

In many languages commas are treated as some form of language construct.  For example in arrays:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

Or in some instances inline string concatenation:

```
var string1 = "yay";
var string2 = "me";
var output = string1, string2;
```

Different languages have different implementations.  You can always use regular expressions to "correct" user input with commas.

If you absolutely have to use commas in your variables, you're probably going to need to use strings.  Which can then be converted to numbers using either regular expressions or your language's parseAsInt(); or parseAsFloat(); equivalent.